# Error while submitting the form data in vuejs

Tags: forms, vue.js

I created a form in vuejs Modal.I want to submit the data to database. All the columns in database table is in varchar. But when I try to create the 'formdata' object from the form the 'phoneNumber' and 'password' throws an error of undefined.I don't understand why these two fields are creating problems. The code looks like this:

```
<form v-on:submit="submitFormData">
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="firstname" v-model="firstname"/>
              {{ firstname }}
              <label for="email">Email Id</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email"/>
              {{email}}
              <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
              <input type="number" name="phoneNumber" v-model="phoneNumber"/>
              {{phoneNumber}}
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" v-model="password"/>
              {{password}}
              <button class="success-button" type="submit">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
```

Now I want to send the data to database on submit. I call a function as below:

```
data() {
return {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    password:"",
  formdata: {},
  errormessage: ""
};
},

  methods: {
    submitFormData(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (this.firstname != "" || this.lastname != "" || this.email != "" || this.phoneNumber !="") {

    this.formdata.firstname = this.firstname;
    this.formdata.lastname = this.lastname;
    this.formdata.email = this.email;
    this.formadata.phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber;
    this.formadata.password = this.password;
    console.log("formdata is ", this.formdata);
    this.$emit("close", this.formdata);
  } else {
    this.errormessage = "Please fill all the details correctly";
  }
}
```

Now it is throwing this error on submit of data:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'phoneNumber' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot set property 'phoneNumber' of undefined
```

Please help me.

Comment: You might want `&&`s instead of `||`s, but the issue is spelling `formadata` has an extra `a` after `form`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a a typo : formadata instead of formdata ;)

That's why it's undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much :) :)